# Unable to setup a docker image with systemd on linux/x86_64 architecture (centos 7) in a mac m1 chipset

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, apple-m1, docker-machine

I've followed the documentation :[Systemd integration on Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos#:%7E:text=reinstall%20your%20package.-,Systemd%20integration,-Systemd%20is%20now)  to create a docker image with **systemd**

Base Image Docker file

```
FROM centos:7
ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

Modified the build command mentioned in documentation from

```
$ docker build --rm -t local/c7-systemd .
```

to

```
$ docker build --platform linux/x86_64  --rm -t local/c7-systemd .
```

Then, built a child docker image
Child image Docker file -

```
FROM local/c7-systemd
RUN yum -y install httpd; yum clean all; systemctl enable httpd.service
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

Modified build file from

```
$ docker build --rm -t local/c7-systemd-httpd .
```

to

```
docker build --platform linux/x86_64 --rm -t local/c7-systemd-httpd .
```

ran the docker with

```
docker run --platform linux/x86_64 -ti -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -p 80:80 local/c7-systemd-httpd
```

Unfortunately got the error message

```
Failed to mount tmpfs at /run: Operation not permitted
Failed to mount cgroup at /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd: Operation not permitted
[!!!!!!] Failed to mount API filesystems, freezing.
```

My requirement is to build a container with

- Apache
- PHP 8.1

with **linux/x86_64** architecture in centos 7

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you need to build a container with systemd? Running any sort of process manager inside a container is generally an anti-pattern (it hides service failures from the container runtime, it prevents you from using existing official images for your tools, and it generally ends up in binding together services that should be able to scale separately).

Answer (score 0):

You can run your container in privileged mode

```
docker run --platform linux/x86_64 --privileged=true -ti -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -p 80:80 local/c7-systemd-httpd
```

Note:
The [CentOS8](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/centos/centos8/images/sha256-65a4aad1156d8a0679537cb78519a17eb7142e05a968b26a5361153006224fdc?context=explore) images have support for linux/arm64/v8 which is the architecture used by Apple Silicon M1.